# How to create a categorical variable from another numeric variable in SPSS?

Tags: data-cleaning, spss

I have a numeric variable in SPSS and I would like to recode it into a different categorical variable(1,2,3) based on if the numeric value of the observations is in the first(1), second(2), or third(3) quartile. I would also like to recode the numeric variable in tertiles. While I know how to find quartiles in SPSS through frequencies, is there a way to recode and create a new variable as I mentioned above? If not, what would I use in the syntax?

Comment: is this what you're trying to do (albeit with one variable rather than multiple)? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-recode-categorical-variable-non-standard-percentiles-spss

Answer (score 0):

Go to Transform -> Visual Binning
Select your variable
Click Make Cutpoints
Select Equal Percentiles
Enter number of cutpoints (2 for tertiles, 3 for quartiles, etc)
Click on Make Labels
Enter the Name of Binned Variable
Click OK